# Разобрать текстовый файл на записи в базе данных

Tags: python, парсер

Есть текстовые файлы вида:

```
dd.mm.gg

Погода была хорошая. Шел дождь, с неба падали лягушки

dd.mm.gg

С погодой и настроением не задалось. Весь день выпяливал тиранозавра.
```

То есть это дневник за месяц.

Как его разобрать последовательно на 2 переменные:
Дата и текст, чтобы отправить в базу данных? дата всегда в рамках 1 месяца, то есть dd.02.14 - февраль 2014 года. Текст может и состоит из нескольких строк. (запись в БД работает, только разобрать надо).
Заранее спасибо :-)

Comment: eсли мeжу тeкстом и датой всeгда стоит пустая строка, то можно сплитить по раздeлитeлю

Comment: Не совсем. В тексте тоже могут быть пробелы. искомый вариант - от даты до даты.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример. На выходе получаем словарь. Ключ - дата. Значение - список дневниковых записей.

```
import re    

file=open("input.txt","r", encoding='utf-8')

reDate="^\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d"
reNote="\w"
notes={}
note=[]
title=""
for line in file:
    if re.match(reDate,line):
        if title!="":
            notes[title]=note
            note=[]
            title=line[:-1]
        else:
            title=line[:-1]
    else:
        if re.match(reNote,line):
            note.append(line)

notes[title]=note

print(notes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так получилось:

```
import os
import datetime


def file_parse(file_name):
    res = []
    i = -1

    with open(file_name) as f:
        my_lines = f.readlines()
        for ln in my_lines:
            ln = ln.replace(u"\u00A0", " ")
            striped_ln = ln.strip()
            if striped_ln == '':
                continue
            if re.search(r'^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}$', striped_ln) is not None:
                dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(striped_ln, '%d.%m.%y')
                res.append(dict(date = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), datetime = dt, text=''))
                i = i + 1
            else:
                res[i]['text'] += ln

    return res


current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
target_file = os.path.join(current_dir, 'dec19.txt')

for it in file_parse(target_file):
    print(it['date'], it['datetime'], it['text'], sep='\n', end='\n\n')
```